# transact-sql seems is outdated and not anymore being supported

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, sqlserver

As soon as I opened the official resource for [Transact-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms189826(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) from the link provided on the official [support page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5) (bottom links), a notice from outdated appears at the top of the Microsoft page.

> This content has been retired and may not be updated in the future.
>   The product, service, or technology mentioned in this content is no
>   longer supported.

What's the actual status of this SQL version supporting SFMC? Can someone give me more insights? Thanks.

Comment: That link references 2005 SQL, MC is no longer of 2005 SQL

Comment: MC s10 is atleast on SQL Server 2016, because it can handle the at timezone function.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks. That means the links on the official documentation are out dated.